# how to return variable from an asychronous call

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have the following function:

```
app.factory('$translation', ['$http', function($http) {

    var getTranslation = function(locale) {
        $http.get("/translations/" + locale + ".json").success(function(data) {
            translations = data;
        });
    };

    getTranslation('en-US');

    var translate = function(input) {
        console.log(translations);
        if(!(input in translations))
            return input;

        var translation = translations[input];
        return translation != null ? translation : input;
    };


    return {
        translate: translate,
        getTranslation: getTranslation
    };

}]);

app.filter('translate', ['$translation', function($translation) {
    return function(input) {
        return $translation.translate(input);
    }
}]);
```

With this function, the `translation` variable is empty when it starts, which makes sense because it is asynchronous. Then, if I navigate in the angular app, I get the translations because the variable is not empty anymore.

Is there a way, where I can somehow make the request synchronous, or at least simulate a synchronous request; so that, the variable exists in the translate function?

EDIT: Copy paste it wrong. Now added the return.

Comment: Look into promises: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q.
Better yet: https://angular-translate.github.io/

Comment: I am going to research promises as I don't quiet understand it from the docs. Angular translate sets the data statically but in my case the language data is stored in a separate file.

Comment: I fully understood the promises but I still can't understand, how I need to return the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `$translate` factory needs to return one/some method functions.

```
angular.factory('$translation', ['$http', function($http) {

    var translations = {};

    var methods = {
           translate       : translate,
           getTranslation  : getTranslation //Not sure if you wanted this as a private function or not...
    };

    return methods;

    function getTranslation(locale) {
         $http.get("/translations/" + locale + ".json").success(function(data) {
             translations = data;
         });
     };

     getTranslation('en-US');

     function translate(input) {
         console.log(translations);
         if(!(input in translations))
         return input;

         var translation = translations[input];
         return translation != null ? translation : input;
     };
}])
```

**Suggestion :** [Don't Use `$` when naming...well anything not related to the main AngularJS library.](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y125)

Comment: Oh crap. I apologize for that, let me update the answer. I made a wrong copy/paste.

Comment: The other main difference I made was defining the `var translations = {}` outside of the two functions. Otherwise it is just a local variable for each and the values aren't shared after running `getTranslation('en-US');`

Comment: Actually I'd recommend using 
     `var getTranslation = function(locale) {
             $http.get("/translations/" + locale + ".json").success(function(data) {
                return data;
             });
         };
     
         var translations = getTranslation('en-US');`

Comment: I did something different. I just refreshed the page after async call was succeeded.